# a large number of apache threads when I do the Apache concurrent test in perfork MPM

Tags: apache, concurrency

My Apache is 2.4.18 in Ubuntu 16.04.

When I do the concurrent test in Jmeter, my test script is like this:
[Test Script in the concurrent testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuXkq.png)

I use `sar -q 1` and `htop` to monitor the number of processes and threads

when it's 5 users concurrent, the the number of processes and threads growth very fast(260 --> 1417 in four minutes)

and I also get the result in `pidstat -wt 1`[Monitor result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzSlC.png)

What's wrong about my apache server?

For my apache server , I use the prefork MPM(use processes).  Why there is so many apache threads?

I try to modify the configuration(cat back the `Time out`/`KeepAliveTimeout`)and `mpm_prefork.conf`, but these don't work to me?

I have no idea about finding the key to the problem. To the first, what should I do?
Really thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[The monitor results in `TOP` command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdJ4X.png)